# keep wp_insert_post from adding duplicates

Tags: wp-insert-post, bulk-import

I have been struggling to import posts from an some json data. The problem is that `wp_insert_post()` is adding multiple versions of the posts. I was previously checking if the post existed by checking if the title existed but there are several posts to be imported that have the same title but different content.

```
function get_all_cpt_ids() {
    global $wpdb;
    $mids = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM tablename.subsite_4_posts WHERE post_type='thing'", OBJECT );

foreach ( $mids as $key => $value ) {
    $thing_ids[] = $value->ID;
}

    return $thing_ids;
}

function mysite_import_json() {


$json_feed = 'http://local.mysite.com/wp-content/test.json';
  $json      = file_get_contents( $json_feed );
  $objs      = json_decode( $json, true );
  $wp_error  = true;
  $id_arr    = [];

foreach ( $objs as $obj ) {
    $id_arr    = get_all_cpt_ids();
    $id        = $obj['nid'];
    $title     = $obj['title'];
    $meta1     = $obj['name'];
    $d         = new DateTime();
    $d->setTimestamp( $obj['created'] );
    $date_created = $d->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
    $post_meta = array(
        'meta_1'        => $meta1,
    );

    $post_data = array(
        'import_id'   => $id,
        'post_title'  => $title,
        'post_date'   => $date_created,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type'   => 'thing',
        'meta_input'  => $post_meta,
    );

    if ( ! in_array( $id_arr, $id, true ) ) {
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data, $wp_error );

        foreach ( $field_meta as $key => $value ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value );
        }
    } 
  }
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mysite_import_json' );
```

As an aside I am doing this all locally so I'm not worried about security when querying the database.

I also set the function to run only once by adding a flag as an option once it has run so I don't really understand why `wp_insert_post()` is running more than once per `$obj` in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: What is `nid` in your JSON?

Comment: an ID from Drupal they start at 32000 or so there shouldn't be any conflicts

Comment: It _is_ odd that you're getting duplicate `$obj` - I assume every entry in you JSON file (i.e. every `$obj`) is indeed unique?

Comment: You should move this line `$id_arr    = get_all_cpt_ids();` out of the loop, you are going to do a query every time you run the loop to get all of the thing ids. And have you verified that WP is actually taking the post_id you are sending it and not using its own. I dont remember if you can define the post_id you want it to use

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Yes the `$obj` is unique. The script works fine if I query and check the title but I need something else to check against

Comment: @stoi2m1 yes, I realise that but it is in an attempt to prevent the same post from being added twice (or more) so I have to query them. In theory I shouldn't have to if I only run the function once. I was wondering the same thing about adding one's own ID.

Comment: @mantis Oh, I see, you rerun the query after adding a post to get the newly add id too, you can append to $id_arr by using `$id_arr[] = $post_id` after you have added the new post? But I dont think this is going to resolve the duplicate issue. Look in the database and see what the IDs are. If they are not your defined IDs we can work on an alternate method of storing the nid so you have something to reference.

Comment: Yes, I tried the `$id_arr[] = $post_id` and it didn't have any effect. I'm looking at the function in the source now and there is an `"import_id" =>0 ` arg to the defaults array. hmm

Comment: I think I might go the wpdb route

Comment: `$post_data = array( 'id' => $id, ..` I don't think it is possible to set the post ID using `wp_insert_post()` as I tried. Maybe update the ID later with a custom query? or could it be `ID` or `post_ID` instead of `id` ? ..

Comment: @Samuel_Elh You're right it is supposed to be `'import_id'   => $id` which does work but doesn't resolve the duplicate posts issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being the hook `after_setup_theme`. I was effectively invoking the function by refreshing the browser which launches the hook in both Javascript and PHP so the hook was being triggered more than once when the browser was refreshed.

Once I disabled Javascript everything worked fine. Another solution would have been to use a different hook that is only triggered once.